# No such Feature Type error

Tags: geoserver, openlayers-2, openlayers

I am trying to insert a Layer with WFS-T and getting an error. I am using ol3 and want to insert data to my database using WFS-t
so this is the GML I defined to do so :

```
formatGML = new ol.format.GML({
    featureNS: 
    'http://localhost:8080/geoserver/wfs/workplace',
    featureType:'layername',
    srsName: 'EPSG:3857'
    });
```

but unfortunately it doesn't work! It is saying :

```
No such feature type http://localhost:8080/geoserver/wfs/workplace:layername
```

Comment: please add the actual XML sent to the server

Comment: do you have a workspace called `workplace` and does it include a layer called `layername`? or do you need to use actual layernames

Comment: yes i do , actually the error was that in the GML i should provide only the workplace without the url , Thanks a lot for your willingness to help

Comment: oh , great , thank you such  @Abdelaziz . It look 2 days to reach here. I will post an answer as the comment section will always gets unnoticed

Answer (score 5):

When updating, you're not supposed to supply the URL of the  feature namespace as value of the `featureNS` property. Instead, you need to supply the namespace prefix (workspace name) as follows:

```
formatGML = new ol.format.GML({
    featureNS: 'your_workspace',
    featureType:'layername',
    srsName: 'EPSG:3857'
    });
```

But while updating, you can give either the full namespace URL bound to `featureNS` or the workspace name only and it will work. Honestly, that looks weird.